# invalid tensorboard callback object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I am having difficulty getting tensorflow callback object working.

after much experimentation i now believe my problem is in the creation of my model. the tutorial i followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViO56ASqeks used tflearn, which is where mine is different from other peoples examples.

I believe (maybe) the problem might be down to 2 log dirs

(a more fundamental base logs folder for all your tensorboard logs)

```
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir=actual_dir)
```

(and the specific callbacks location)

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
```

simplified example of entire problem below

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tensorflow as tf 
import datetime
print(tf.__version__)

raw_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\tgmjack\\Desktop\\ml area\\c v d\\PetImages\\raw"
MODEL_NAME = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(1e-3, '2conv-basic') # just so we remember which saved model is which, sizes must match
actual_dir = "C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop"


def make_model():
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    convnet = input_data(shape=[None, 1, 1, 1], name='input')
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=1e-3, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir=actual_dir)
    model.save(actual_dir+"/"+MODEL_NAME)
    return model

X = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
test_x= [0,1]
test_y= [0,1]

model = make_model()
logdir = os.path.join("logs\cvd", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}) ,
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME , callbacks =[tensorboard_callback]  )
```

the entire ouput below is

```
2.9.1
INFO:tensorflow:C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop/dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model is not in all_model_checkpoint_paths. Manually adding it.
INFO:tensorflow:C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop\dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model
INFO:tensorflow:0
INFO:tensorflow:C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop\dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model.data-00000-of-00001
INFO:tensorflow:400
INFO:tensorflow:C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop\dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model.index
INFO:tensorflow:400
INFO:tensorflow:C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop\dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model.meta
INFO:tensorflow:500
---------------------------------
Run id: dogsvscats-0.001-2conv-basic.model
Log directory: C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop/
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Accuracy/ (raw) is illegal; using Accuracy/__raw_ instead.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 37>()
     35 logdir = os.path.join("logs\cvd", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
     36 tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
---> 37 model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}) ,
     38           snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME , callbacks =[tensorboard_callback]  )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py:196, in DNN.fit(self, X_inputs, Y_targets, n_epoch, validation_set, show_metric, batch_size, shuffle, snapshot_epoch, snapshot_step, excl_trainops, validation_batch_size, run_id, callbacks)
    194 # Retrieve data preprocesing and augmentation
    195 daug_dict, dprep_dict = self.retrieve_data_preprocessing_and_augmentation()
--> 196 self.trainer.fit(feed_dicts, val_feed_dicts=val_feed_dicts,
    197                  n_epoch=n_epoch,
    198                  show_metric=show_metric,
    199                  snapshot_step=snapshot_step,
    200                  snapshot_epoch=snapshot_epoch,
    201                  shuffle_all=shuffle,
    202                  dprep_dict=dprep_dict,
    203                  daug_dict=daug_dict,
    204                  excl_trainops=excl_trainops,
    205                  run_id=run_id,
    206                  callbacks=callbacks)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:314, in Trainer.fit(self, feed_dicts, n_epoch, val_feed_dicts, show_metric, snapshot_step, snapshot_epoch, shuffle_all, dprep_dict, daug_dict, excl_trainops, run_id, callbacks)
    311 callbacks = to_list(callbacks)
    313 if callbacks:
--> 314     [caller.add(cb) for cb in callbacks]
    316 caller.on_train_begin(self.training_state)
    317 train_ops_count = len(self.train_ops)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py:314, in <listcomp>(.0)
    311 callbacks = to_list(callbacks)
    313 if callbacks:
--> 314     [caller.add(cb) for cb in callbacks]
    316 caller.on_train_begin(self.training_state)
    317 train_ops_count = len(self.train_ops)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\callbacks.py:88, in ChainCallback.add(self, callback)
     86 def add(self, callback):
     87     if not isinstance(callback, Callback):
---> 88         raise Exception(str(callback) + " is an invalid Callback object")
     90     self.callbacks.append(callback)

Exception: <keras.callbacks_v1.TensorBoard object at 0x000002477036C580> is an invalid Callback object
```

please, if anyone could show me this working... i really have tried every imaginable combination of directories written in different formats (ive been stuck on this 1 little thing for like 3 weeks) ive also tried clearing out all my logs, changing my working directory, switch between anaconda notebook or idle... etc...

###### Yet another update

Below is an example of the files that get created when i run without callbacks. Tensorboard cannot see these files. It doesnt crash now :) . but tensorboard sees no data. i have tried this with much more complex data too its not the empty arbitrary data thats causing it

[image]

left: files created

right: tensorboard

ps) i only have 1 folder on this whole computer called cvd2, so both the files and my tensorboard seem to be in the right place... so how could it miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

For managing Tensorboard in a `tflearn.DNN` model, you have to first set a `tensorboard_dir` where the logs will be saved. However, this does not tells the model to save the logs, just where they can be saved if needed.

Having a look at the [tflearn documentation](http://tflearn.org/models/dnn/), in order to enable saving the logs for TensorBoard, you have to set the parameter `tensorflow_verbose` (see also [here](http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#visualization) for more info).
For best visualization it is suggested setting `tensorflow_verbose=3`. At this point you're all set-up, no need for callbacks.

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import tensorflow as tf 
import datetime
print(tf.__version__)

MODEL_NAME = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(1e-3, '2conv-basic') # just so we remember which saved model is which, sizes must match
actual_dir = "/my/path/"


def make_model():
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    convnet = input_data(shape=[None, 1, 1, 1], name='input')
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=1e-3, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir=actual_dir, tensorboard_verbose=3)
    model.save(actual_dir+"/"+MODEL_NAME)
    return model

X = [[[[0]]]]
Y = [[0, 0]]

model = make_model()
model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3 ,
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

To view Tensorboard and your logs, just call the instruction below as always:

```
%tensorboard --logdir='/my/path'
```

Comment: hi, I allready am in the folder where my logs folder is. ive added an image to show this.

Comment: Hi @tgm_learn, no problem. I've updated the answer. Keep me posted

Comment: your suggestion works fine, im trying to apply the same thing (moving to the desktop and doing stuff from there) to my script. 

but it just does not want to work for mine. i still get the same error with new working directories and stuff :/ 

I'm gunna keep trying.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be an issue, but maybe the problem is that your `logs/cvd` is used also for other files other than the logs. Try with an empty folder at the location that you like. @tgm_learn

Comment: hi, so it seems to be ignoring my instruction on the logdir and just using the working directory, my newest update shows this

Comment: So, let's recap. The tutorial works also for you. But at the same location your code doesn't. Have you tried keeping separated the logs and saved model? Keep the folder just for the logs. That being said, it might be worth if you made a small reproducible example of your code. I took a look at the complete notebook and found no obvious problems. Maybe if you simplify it a bit the problem will come up @tgm_learn

Comment: hi , Ive simplified the problem, so its all just a few lines now :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, I was able to reproduce the error. It is working for me now, let me know if it is solved also for you! @tgm_learn

Comment: so i dont need callbacks?

Comment: no, you don't. the updated code works for me... and for you? @tgm_learn

Comment: i cant quite get tensorboard to see any of the data still. It doesnt crash now. I thought it might be because of how basic and empty the data is so i applied this stuff to my cats and dogs image classifier and still no data for tensorboard. Ive added an update with evidence of what is created.

Comment: yes the data is in the right place, and you should be able to see it connecting to `http://localhost:6006/`. Silly question, have you refreshed the TensorBoard page after the creation of the data? If this does not work try killing the TensorBoard process. The cell should give you a suggestion on how to do it if you try to start the process with same path twice (the command will be something like `!kill your_number`. Execute this command in a cell). Then try starting the process setting the full path of the logs (e.g. `%tensorboard --logdir="/Users/claudia/Desktop/logs/cvd2"`) @tgm_learn